# Move multiple images to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using the `move_upload()` function. I names all the images differently. It uploads to databse with the right names but it does not display in the image folder.

below is my code  for the images part as evrything else uploads correctly.

```
echo $post_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

echo $post_imagea=$_FILES['imagea']['name'];

echo $post_imageb=$_FILES['imageb']['name'];

echo $image_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


echo $imagea_tmp=$_FILES['imagea']['tmp_name'];

echo $imageb_tmp=$_FILES['imageb']['tmp_name'];

echo $post_description=$_POST['description'];

echo $post_description=$_POST['description'];



if($post_title=='' or $post_keywords=='' or $post_description=='' or $post_price==''){
    echo "<script> alert('none of the fields can be empty, try again')</script>";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image/");
}
```

Comment: what is this                                                     echo $image_tmp=$_FILES['imagea']['tmp_name'];

echo $image_tmp=$_FILES['imageb']['tmp_name'];   imagea and imageb

Comment: thats the second image i called it imagea in the database as well

Comment: @wild its this sorry 
echo $imagea_tmp=$_FILES['imagea']['tmp_name'];

echo $imageb_tmp=$_FILES['imageb']['tmp_name'];

echo $post_description=$_POST['description'];

Comment: @wild the error is Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace it**

```
 move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image/");
```

**with**

```
 move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/".$post_image);
```

Comment: i did that only uploads the first image

Comment: use it   move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/".$post_image);
 move_uploaded_file($imagea_tmp,"../images/".$post_imagea);
 move_uploaded_file($imageb_tmp,"../images/".$post_imageb);

Comment: because you have three image so three time use move_uploaded_file();

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the right permissions on the /images/ map ??

it should have read/write/execute permissions in order to move your image to the folder

Comment: yes it does have right permissions, as it uploads when i do one file not the multiple files. im not sure how i should structure the moveupload() to include both imagea and imageb. any ideas?

Comment: only the first image uploads to the move_uploaded_files() no other, how do i get all of them to upload.